# Perforated patches: Can antibiotics used to induce holes in membrane produce perforations of differential size?

Tags: neuroscience

Perforated patches are a special type of patch clamping. I understand that it is sometimes preferred to whole-cell recordings because it prevents complete diffusion of the electrode solution into the clamped cell, but I was wondering:

Can the antibiotics/antifungals used to induce holes into the membrane produce perforations of differential size, so that the researcher can control which types of molecules will make it into the cell?

Maybe somebody has experience with this technique (I have never done it myself), and could share why they prefer it to whole-cell recordings.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a biology question. I think?

Comment: @ChristianHummeluhr - I agree. i actually have made a short-lived attempt to look into answering this question with no luck. personally the antibiotic-mediated perforation is unknown to me and finding it in the literature was unsuccessful on a few tries. Perhaps a clarification request would help.

Comment: But I agree, it is off-topic here